# ChartJS Add data from string

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to fill my douhnut chart with data I get from my backend but it isn't working..

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

```
var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var pieOptions = { ... };
var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
```

Problem is with the 'PieData'.
If I'm making this in the javascript:

```
var PieData =
  [
   {
     value: 400,
     color: "#f39c12",
     highlight: "#f39c12",
     label: "FireFox"
   }
  ];
```

Everything works fine.

But I want to set the values from my backend:

```
var token2 = document
.querySelector('script[data-id="MyUniqueName"][data-token2]')
.getAttribute('data-token2');
```

with token2 = "{ value: 100, color: '#00a65a', highlight: '#00a65a', label: 'IE' }"

I tried adding the [] in the string, or making var data = [token2] but nothing is working.

I'm bad at javascript, so maybe someone knows my answer.

**EDIT**:

I am working with ASP.NET/C# for my website.
The method I'm using to give the data to the javascript is:
*HTML page:*

```
<scrpt type='text/javascript' data-id="MyUniqueName" data-token2="<%=Data%>" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/dist/js/pages/dashboard2.js")%>' ></script>
```

*C#*:

```
private String _data = String.Empty;
protected String Data {
        get {
        return this._data;
        }
        set {
            this._data = value;
        }
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Data = "{ value: 100, color: '#00a65a', highlight: '#00a65a', label: 'IE' } ";
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify? How are you trying to set values from your backend? What language? NodeJS? I use ChartJS library and just do something like <?php echo "{ value: 100, color: '#00a65a', highlight: '#00a65a', label: 'IE' }"; ?> where it's needed...

Comment: @BozidarSikanjic See edit on question

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my c# code to:

```
Data = "{ &quot;value&quot;: &quot;100&quot;, &quot;color&quot;: &quot;#00a65a&quot;, &quot;highlight&quot;: &quot;#00a65a&quot;, &quot;label&quot;: &quot;IE&quot; } ";
```

I needed to quote everything, and it wasnt working with `\"` , i needed to put `&quot`

And with JSON converted it to an object:

```
var PieData = JSON.parse(token2);
```

I'm not really sure if this is the best solution, but it's working for now.